# rounding numbers in a dictionary to unique integers

Tags: python, dictionary

I have used the pandas [rank function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) to get a dictionary

In the cases where values are tied the rank function gives, non-integer values. For example

```
{'EHS': 11.0,
 'Engineering': 4.5,
 'GPS': 9.5,
 'Logistics': 3.0,
 'NPI & Technical': 7.0,
 'OSD': 8.0,
 'Quality': 1.5,
 'RSC & Micronising': 1.5,
 'Strategy': 4.5,
 'Tech': 6.0,
 'Unknown Function': 9.5}
```

I want to round all non-integers to the nearest unique integer. I don't mind whether they are rounded up or down, so if engineering was rounded to 4 and strategy was rounded to 5 or vica versa I would be happy.

Using dictionary.values() I have been able to get the values but am not sure what the best way to round the values and put them back in the dictionary

Comment: What if this is not possible? For example, `{'A': 4.5, 'B': 4.5, 'C': 4.5}`?

Comment: What's your desired output? When you say "unique integer", that makes me think you're looking for more than just rounding. And you seem to have a typo: "if **engineering** was rounded to 4 and **engineering** was rounded to 5"

Comment: because the dictionary comes from the rank function its always possible

Comment: Instead of adding the result from rank, you can actually include the dataframe itself on which this rank is being  calculated.

Comment: Doesn't the `rank` function support directly giving you what you desire?

Comment: could you explain how to get it out of the rank function - I cant see it in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem. At least for the case that you presented.

[Edit: modify the code after the new comment]. if you want the number to be sequential in this case, you can do the following:

```
d = {'EHS': 11.0,
 'Engineering': 4.5,
 'GPS': 9.5,
 'Logistics': 3.0,
 'NPI & Technical': 7.0,
 'OSD': 8.0,
 'Quality': 1.5,
 'RSC & Micronising': 1.5,
 'Strategy': 4.5,
 'Tech': 6.0,
 'Unknown Function': 9.5}
ranks = list(range(1,len(d)+1))
for x,y in enumerate(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[1] )):
    d[y[0]] = ranks.pop(0)
print(d)
```

Note: as explained in the comments. If you are using the rank function, you can directly obtain the result. You are getting floats because pandas does not know the method to rank the column you have. You have to specify the method to get integers.

E.g:

```
df['my_col'].rank(method='first')
```

will give integer ranks.

Comment: Thanks, this works really well - but it doesn't work where the key values are numerical, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean . Could you give an example?

Comment: https://sharetext.me/ykacbkca here is the dictionary i am working with

Comment: @Abijah you can  check the new edit. It should work for your current dictionary